# List some Functions of Libraries on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, libraries

While doing some tests on my Linux Machine, I need to find which Functions belong to some Library.

I used the bash Command "ldconfig -p", which listed some Library.

But how to list the Functions ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? List the files? List symbols within a library? Locate a symbol at runtime?

Comment: It's very possible that the library you're after isn't available on your system right now... you might need to install it.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood something, those Libraries were not Libraries. Yes I need to list the Symbols(Functions?) of a Library e.g. libc .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `objdump -tT ${FILE}` or `readelf -s ${FILE}`.

```
$ objdump -T /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000001c58 l    d  .init  0000000000000000              .init
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3.4 __snprintf_chk
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 free
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __errno_location
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 write
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strlen
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.4   __stack_chk_fail
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 snprintf
[...]
00000000000024c0 g    DF .text  00000000000000f9  ZLIB_1.2.2  adler32_combine
0000000000002ba0 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  ZLIB_1.2.3.3 crc32_combine64
0000000000010170 g    DF .text  0000000000000074  Base        gzdopen
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  ZLIB_1.2.7.1 ZLIB_1.2.7.1
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  ZLIB_1.2.3.3 ZLIB_1.2.3.3
000000000000c780 g    DF .text  0000000000000036  Base        inflateSyncPoint
00000000000104f0 g    DF .text  0000000000000059  ZLIB_1.2.3.5 gzoffset64
0000000000011160 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  ZLIB_1.2.5.2 gzgetc_
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  ZLIB_1.2.3.4 ZLIB_1.2.3.4
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  ZLIB_1.2.3.5 ZLIB_1.2.3.5
00000000000043a0 g    DF .text  00000000000000cd  ZLIB_1.2.5.2 deflateResetKeep
0000000000010550 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  ZLIB_1.2.3.5 gzoffset
000000000000fdd0 g    DF .text  0000000000000023  Base        gzclose
[...]
```

In `objdump`'s output:

- Any symbol marked `*UND*` is resident in another library ([dynamically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker))

  - for example `free`, `write`, etc...
- Any symbol with a section (e.g: `.init` or `.text`) is resident in this library

  - for example `gzdopen`, `gzclose`, etc...

---

You can use `ldd` to find out what libraries a binary (executable or library) links with:

```
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc478f7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92da469000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f92daa4d000)
```